Linux Distros not booting, import_mok_state() not found
I have a MS Surface Book 2 with Debian, running the Linux Surface custom kernel. While trying to reinstall the kernel I clearly deleted some package I wasn't supposed to (linux-surface-secureboot-mok I believe?).
My machine now doesn't boot Debian or Ubuntu at all, not even from LiveCD and gives completely no errors, just hangs at the very first boot screen. Other distros (tested Mint and PopOS) give the following error before shutting down:
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\mmx64.efi - Not Found
Failed to load image : Not Found
Failed to start MokManager: Not Found
Something has gone seriously wrong: import_mok_state() failed: Not Found 

I've tried disabling and reenabling secure boot and the TPM, but nothing I do seems to fix this apart from renaming the grub efi file to mmx64.efi (and that only works for Mint and PopOS, not for Debian and Ubuntu).
I will seriously appreciate any ideas you guys have.

Did you get anywhere on this? All the answers I can find are a little unclear!

I fixed it by installing ventoy on a usb and running it. It had mokmanager installed and it signed the keys or whatever just fine.
Though it still doesn‘t work on my main os. When I installed the kernel again I had to go through the same process
